# sapply function to populate a column of a data frame from values in a named vector taking a very long time. Is there a faster way?

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is an example of what I am doing.

```
x <- c(a="2",b="4",c="2",d="9")
df <- data.frame(names = c("d","c","a","b"))
```

`x` is a named vector of values in a different order from how they appear in `df$names`. I need to form a new column in the data frame which takes the values from `x`. Here's what I wrote.

```
df$vals <- sapply(df$names,function(t) x[t])
```

This code works fine with this toy example, but I am working with a data frame that has over 150,000 rows and this is just taking an obscenely long time. Is `sapply` a slow way to do this?

Comment: Presumably your dataframe is not in exact reverse order of your `x` names :-(   ... and all `x` names exist in the dataframe.

Comment: All of the `x` names do exist in the data frame. To provide some more context, an `igraph` graph was generated via various other processes where each entry in `df$names` is a vertex in the graph. `x` is a vector of the degrees of all the vertices. The names of the vertices are preserved, but I have no idea how the order of the vertices was determined in `igraph`—some black magic presumably. So now I am taking the degrees of the vertices in the `igraph` graph and putting them back into the data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df$vals <- x[match(df$names, names(x))]
```

`match` is very fast (20 times+ in this example case).

Comment: awesome. Is there a reason that my method should be so slow?

Comment: wow I just ran this code and it was practically instantaneous. My code was actually unmanageably slow.

Comment: `match` is designed for such purposes. `sapply` will create overhead. (Afaik, the apply-family commands are convenient substitutes for loops to make R more like an interactive command line exploration tool than just a programing language.)

Comment: @crf yea I remember thinking the same when I found out about it. :)