# R - for loop alternative to conditionally populating tuples?

Tags: r

Have a `data.frame` with numeric values, and a character vector. The character vector is *not* a named character (unlike [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21528883/sapply-function-to-populate-a-column-of-a-data-frame-from-values-in-a-named-vect)).

The toy code below achieves what I'm looking to do, but I've been trying to shy away from `for` loops and either use the `*apply` family or other functions available in `{base}`.

```
df = data.frame(act_val = c(1:10))
temp = letters[1:10]

for (i in 1:length(temp)){
    df$act_name[df$act_val == i] = temp[i]
}
```

So, IFF `act_val == 1` then `act_name == "a"`. I realize this is somewhat a bastardized version of a named character vector, where the position of the character is effectively being used as what the value `names()` would be.

All that said, there must be a more R-like way?

Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can vectorize the lookup with `temp[df$act_val]` and then assign to the column:

```
df$act_name = temp[df$act_val]
```

Comment: Most days I have moments... Thanks tons, worked perfectly. Will accept as soon as I'm allowed (~5 mins to go). Michael